# Scrollview and Tablelayout usage with banner to bottom in xml

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, gravity, banner

[image]This is my xml file. There are 35 xml files like this in my app. Their textview and button numbers are different. Some of them are more than 10 , some of are less than 5. But considering the devices screen, i designed all xml files using scroll view. Also i needed tablelayout and used tablelayout, table row inside it and textviews inside tablerows. When i finished the app everything was ok. Now i added mobile ad banners in xml files and it started to crash.

If i add the banner just before ending of tablelayout , app doesnt crash and ad is displayed at teh end of table but the vision is too bad.Because if there are 3 rows in the xml then the banner takes place after the last textview and this is something like the middle of the page. No matter how many textviews the xml use, i want them to be scrollable and in the end i want the banner take place at the end of the page.

I tried some android:gravity="bottom" or

alignparentbottom="true" things but they didn't work. In my researches i realised that i may need to add some linear or relative layout codes but when i tried them thay dont fit with scrollview and crash. Here is one of the xml files. How should i need to modify this ?

In the images , First one is how it works , the banner takes place where the textview ends , i want the second image , no matter how long the tetviews the banner should be at the bottom of the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue">


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="TRY"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

            </TextView>
// some other buttons or textviews...


 </TableRow> 
 </TableLayout>
 <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
  android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the banner needs to be always shown at the bottom, 
you can set the weight of the ScrollView in a LinearLayout to 1.

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/blue">
    <ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dip" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/blue">


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TRY"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        </TextView>
// some other buttons or textviews...
    </TableRow> 
 </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
 android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No this one didnt solve the problem. Originally the top level is scrollview , in your solution the linearlayout comes first and then the scrollview is in it. I tried it but lost the members in scrollview. Everything has gone.

Comment: The orientation in the Root LinearLayout should be vertical. Please look at the updated xml

Comment: Looks like the closest answer is this. I tried it with a textview instead of banner and it looks ok but when i use banner the ad is not being displayed. I have no idea why it doesnt show the advertisement. Nothing is being displayed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the code here because I do not have the Banner component but try wrapping both the TableLayout and the Banner in a LinearLayout.

#### modified layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="TRY"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    
            </TableRow> 
    
        </TableLayout>
        
        <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
            android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
        
</ScrollView>
```

#### UPDATE

After testing the file locally I realized that crash is being caused by the Banner because a ScrollView can have only one child.  I'm surprised that you were able to compile your project with the error in the layout file.  So one solution is wrap the TableLayout and Banner in a LinearLayout.  See example 1:

#### example 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/table"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:text="TRY"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          />

      </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
        android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After thinking about it, it may be possible to eliminate the TableLayout completely.  You can use a LinearLayout to stack items on top of each other.  So that would simplify your layout file quite a bit.  See example 2.

#### example 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="TRY"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        
        <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
            android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
        
</ScrollView>
```

## UPDATE 2

Then your issue must be with your Java file.  I have tested the layout file locally and it does render properly.  See screenshot below.  [image: example 1 layout screenshot]

## UPDATE 3

The solution required updates to both the layout file and the Activity class.  The logic is fairly simple.  If the number of rows in the table cause the table height to exceed the height of the scrollview, then scrolling is enabled.  If scrolling is enabled, the banner ad is appended as child of the table.  If scrolling is disabled, the banner ad is inserted as a child of the linearlayout.  In order to determine the correct heights it is necessary to subscribe to the OnGlobalLayout event.  The following code is a ** working sample ** of what you will need.  In order to test both scenarios (scrolling enabled/disabled) just change the value of the ROW_COUNT variable. I used 3 for scrolling disabled and 30 for enabled.  You will see the banner placed appropriately.

#### activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
      android:id="@id/scrollview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#e0e0e0">

      <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="TRY" />

        </TableRow>


      </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

  private static String TAG = "TestActivity";
  private Activity mActivity;
  private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
  private TableLayout mTableLayout;
  private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

  private static int ROW_COUNT = 30;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    mActivity = this;
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    mTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final int padding = (int)Math.floor((density * 20f));

    for(int i=0;i<ROW_COUNT;i++){
      TextView view = new TextView(mActivity);
      view.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      view.setPadding(padding,padding,padding,padding);
      view.setText("TableRow");

      TableRow row = new TableRow(mActivity);
      row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      row.addView(view);

      mTableLayout.addView(row);
    }

    ViewTreeObserver observer = mRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
        if(view == null){
          view = new TextView(mActivity);
          view.setId(R.id.banner);
          view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
          view.setText("BannerAd");
          view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
          view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          view.setPadding(0, padding, 0, padding);
          if(mTableLayout.getHeight() > mLinearLayout.getHeight()) {
            mTableLayout.addView(view);
          }else{
            mLinearLayout.addView(view);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I can post screenshots if needed, but test this code out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work , still the same. The banner takes place where the last textview ends. Actually you dont need to try the banner , you can try a button or a textview instead of banner and you can test it. It would do the same thing.

Comment: Ok I will try it with a Button and reply soon.

Comment: Thank you i will be waiting.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. You should be all set.

Comment: Didn't work , same results. I cannot remove the tablelayout , i need it and example 1 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please see updates to the answer.  You may need to post your Java code (Activity) as well.  Also, please post a screenshot of the issue you are seeing on the Android device.

Comment: I updated the question and added screenshots. There is no problem on java code , it is only xml. as i said before when i used your example 1 code it works like the first screenshot. I want the second one.

Comment: And i didn't understand your update. In your screenshot try is textview content and the image is banner , isn't it ? so if you take this image to the bottom the problem is solved .

Comment: Ok I thought you wanted the Banner below the TableView but actually you want it anchored to the bottom of the window if the TableView height is less than the window height. If the tableview height is greater than the window height, then anchor it to the bottom of the tableview. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes if it is less than window , i want the banner at bottom . If the table is greater than window the scrollview should work and everything must be visible by scrolling. And in the end the banner should be at the bottom again.

Comment: The problem is solved , thank you for your interest.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Again, the initial error was that you had two items nested inside a ScrollView and that is what caused the app to crash.  After some discussion and screenshots I understood that you wanted to the Banner add to have dynamic placement. Specifically, if the tableview height exceeds the height of the window then anchor the banner to the bottom of the tableview; else anchor the banner to the bottom of the window.  I have implemented that using both an updated layout file and Activity class.  It works great.